# find angle between faces from face normals

Tags: 3d, geometry, angle

I have some face normals and I need to calculate the angle between the faces they belong to. The problem I'm having is with finding angles between faces when the angle is greater than 180 - I can't figure out how to tell the difference between an angle of 45 and an angle of 315.

edit2:
I have access to the obj file defining the model, what information would i need to differentiate between 45' and 315'? Also, I am building the (low-poly) models used, so I can guarantee no intersecting faces, etc.

edit:

```
ang = math.acos(dotproduct(v1, v2) / (length(v1) * length(v2)))

ang = math.degrees(ang)

ang = 360 - (ang + 180)
```

Comment: maybe you should post your code, what you've tried so far. (Maybe even in pseudo code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ensure that your normals are unit length (divide by their length if necessary).  Then find the dot product.

```
dp = n1.x*n2.x + n1.y*n2.y + n1.z*n2.z
```

This will give a value in [-1 to 1].
**If dp is negative, the angle is greater than 90 degrees.**

To find the angle, use arc-cosine.

```
θ = acos(dp);
```

That will give you the value in radians.  To convert to degrees, multiply by 180/pi.

---

Edit: Assume the faces are defined as polygons.  If the faces are not co-planar, there must exist one point in each face's polygon definition that is not co-planar with the other polygon.  Consider two triangles: if one edge is connected, they share two vertices but each have one un-shared vertex.  I'll call these **v1** and **v2** associated respectively with normals **n1** and **n2**.  Find the vector from **v1** to **v2**:

```
m = v2-v1
```

If the angle between **m** and **n1** is greater than 90 [**dotP(m,n1)<0**] then the polygons face away from each other.  If the angle is less than 90, the polygons are facing toward each other.  If the angle is 90 degrees, then I think that the polygons are co-planar (or one of your chosen points is on the line of planar intersection or I've missed a case in my thinking).

Comment: Wouldn't the angle between the faces be `180 - (angle between normals)` (assuming angle-between-normals < 180)?

Comment: Also note that using a dot product there's no way to differentiate between 45' and 315'

Comment: There's also no difference between 45 and 315 degrees.  Or rather, you can't really have an angle of 315 _between_ two vectors.  It doesn't make sense.  If you want the counter-clockwise angle between two 2D vectors: n2 with respect to n1, then you should find: atan2(n2.y,n2.x) and atan2(n1.y,n1.x), then subtract the angle of n1 from n2 (and then ensure a positive value).

Comment: @BlueRaja  I guess I consider the normal of the face to define the direction it's 'facing'.  To calculate the angle made at the joining point of two faces, you need more information: you need to have two reference points-- one on each of the faces.

Comment: Actually, that's probably not true since the surfaces could be intersecting, in which case the question is hard to answer.  I guess you need the point of intersection and then a vector that defines which way is 'out'.

Comment: I have access to the obj file defining the model, what information would i need to differentiate between 45' and 315'? Also, I am building the (low-poly) models used, so I can guarantee no intersecting faces.

Comment: I think so, but I'll need to put together some tests before I know